# Correct way to invoke remove_if

Tags: c++, stl

In the following sample code `remove_if` is supposed to delete all even numbers but it is not working as I expect.  I am obviously doing something wrong since the output continues to show some even numbers, towards the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool
myCond(int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }


int
main ()
{
  vector<int> myVector = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22};
  
  remove_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), myCond);
  
  for(int i : myVector) cout << i << " ";
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

output 11 13 15 17 19 16 17 18 19 20 22

Comment: You've done one half of the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). You still need to do the erase. It's a bit of an implementation detail that you have to go through this two-step process.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://godbolt.org/z/6zWWa1z59) with the explained steps.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) only move the elements that need to be removed to the end of the container, you still need to use [`vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) to actually erase them.

If your compiler supports C++20, then I recommend using [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) which is more intuitive and less error-prone:

```
vector<int> myVector = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22};
std::erase_if(myVector, myCond);
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/e6Y4EohaM)

Comment: anyone reading this is going to wonder *why* it works that way! The answer is basically so you can mix-and-match different containers with different functions (like remove_if). Different containers have different ways to remove things, so you have to do that instead of remove_if doing it.

Answer (score 0):

`remove_if` returns an iterator - which will be the end of the rearranged items.

You can change you `for` loop to stop when it gets to the new end.

Comment: Or use `std::vector<int>::erase()` with the returned interator (it seems the OP wants to remove the even elements from the vector).

Answer (score 0):

`std::remove_if` returns an iterator to the first element removed. In other words, everything before the iterator is evaluated to be `false`.

Have a look at the [reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/), especially the `Return value` paragraph.

For us, this means we have to iterate to returned iterator (the new end) if we want to print the odd values -- or we erase all elements from the returned iterator to `end()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool myCond(int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myVector = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22};
  
  auto rm_it = std::remove_if(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), myCond);
        
  // Possibility 1: Print odd values
  auto it = myVector.cbegin();
  for (; it != rm_it; ++it) std::cout << *it << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  
  // Possibility 2: Erase values from the vector
  myVector.erase(rm_it, myVector.end());
  for(int i : myVector) std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `remove_if` isn't `partition`, everything after the iterator is a moved-from value